# Why does TypeScript pick a different overload on function reference vs. a lambda-warpped call?

Tags: typescript, overloading, type-inference

Why does TS pick the last overloaded variant, and not the middle `f(x: string): string` one in the last case, where it gives a type of `(string | null)[]` instead of `string[]`?

(TypeScript version 4.4.4)

```js
function f(x: null): null;
function f(x: string): string;
function f(x: string | null): string | null;

function f(x: string | null): string | null {
  if (x === null) return x;
  return `${x}`;
}

f(null); // null
f('foo'); // string
f(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'bar' : null); // string | null

['a', 'b', 'c'].map(x => f(x)); // string[]
['a', 'b', 'c'].map(f); // (string | null)[]
```

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with not being able to find an exact match for the signature (since `map` calls its callback with three arguments, not one)... (The fact it even allows you to use `f` there is a bit of laxness on TypeScript's part [probably pragmatic, intentional laxness]. It wouldn't let you do `.map((x, i, a) => f(x, i, a))` for instance, which is the same thing.) Enh, maybe not... I tried creating a three-parameter (two optional) version of `f` and got the same result.

Comment: It's a design limitation in TS, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35501 .  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69991802/is-there-any-way-to-extract-all-of-the-function-signatures-from-an-overloaded-ts/69992248#69992248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design limitation in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#35501](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35501) for an authoritative answer.

[Overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) resolution is only guaranteed to happen properly when you do not require any [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#types-by-inference) to happen first.  If you call the overloaded function directly with arguments of known types, that will work as expected.  But any manipulation of the overloaded function signature where the compiler needs to infer types will use some heuristic to eagerly choose or synthesize a single call signature from the list of overloads without regard for which signature would actually be appropriate if called directly.  This tends to be the last call signature (or maybe the first sometimes? according to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30369#issuecomment-476402214)).

In your case, the [array `map()` method](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/009dd487a6543d16c8e403ea055ac0683c6bc5d3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1361) needs to [infer a generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#inference) `U` corresponding to the return type of the callback function.  The compiler eagerly picks the last call signature, sees that its return type is `string | null`, and goes with that:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].map(f); // (string | null)[]
```

This problem also occurs in [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) including the popular [`Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType<T>` utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype):

```
type FParam = Parameters<typeof f>[0]; // type FParam = string | null
type FReturn = ReturnType<typeof f>; // type FReturn = string | null
```

---

For your example, if you want to call `map()` without wrapping `f` in `x => f(x)`, you can sidestep the problem by manually specifying the generic type parameter:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].map<string>(f); // string[]
```

Now there's no type inference necessary... the compiler knows that `U` is `string`, and thus it needs to interpret `f` as a value of type `(value: string) => string`.  Without inference, overload resolution happens as expected here, and so the second overload is chosen and no compiler error happens.  And of course since you specified `U` as `string`, the return type of the map operation `string[]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.4.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFADwFyLCANrgSix3wG4BYAKFElgWXSwGcoAnGMAcyMRfa4rVw0eElSZebDp0QAfbHkLMpXOQrJUqNEfXHL+M+SSWSDa44gDeVRLcQxgidIgC8b9YUSsAplBCskNEE7L19-JAADABJLNABfCME4zWoUYwJSRAB6LI8tFAByYDg4Aozs3L5pfIBZAEMoAAsAOlY6sAATOABbFAJEAD5EAAZmgFZEAH5EAoAjOtYCxGJFcpzTaXNFFIBtArqCgBoZ2aOZiAKAXWbuuoAHZxch8QI1ypVOHcuqPYPjubOBQu11uD2AbycVVURlWXxSVCgAE87t5EAAxAAKCzq3VciCxbW6vm8rCYAB4kSi4I5gAMdsNLpl1pTUZjsbiXBtoXlKCz0QAlMIBPGCvwBAAqyO8FKl1OQAyZuT5aNF4TxUMMPJS2joSDqEAg3juUAA8gA3Em4OB1DreDooCCzLDWSghRgeHhmuAwDrBOzujWe72+qhxfqWRDJShUfWG43my3W2328GKxBwADWdURMYNRtNFtYVptdpQZtcQwgCCYcFw3maVs4ZdeafLMCY9jAwBJPg6iDqHY1W3w8Mov0Bp3+wJu9zJGoGKFTFS5n2+lCAA)